# Getting an IList<field_type> from IList<object_type>

Tags: c#, linq, ilist

I have an `IList<Person>` object. The Person class has fields, `FirstName`, `LastName`, etc.

I have a function which takes `IList<string>` and I want to pass in the list of FirstNames in the same order of the `IList<Person>` object. Is there a way to do this without building List with all of the names from the Person list?

What if I could change the function to take a different parameter (other than `ILIst<Person>`, the function is specific to strings, not Persons), maybe `IEnumerable<string>`? I'd rather use the `IList<string>` though.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: He has an `IList<Person>` ... he wants to change that into an `IList<string>`, whose contents are `Person.FirstName`.

Comment: Do you really want `IList<string>`, or does `IReadOnlyList<string>` suffice? `IList<string>` also includes methods such as `Add`, which won't work for you. A `IReadOnlyList<TTarget> Select<TSource, TTarget>(this IReadOnlyList<TSource> list, Func<TSource, TTarget> func)` extension method would be easy enough to create.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Enumerable.Select` will return an IEnumerable of strings (first names) for you.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx

`myFunction(people.Select(o => o.FirstName))`

You could also add in the ToList() if you really want to pass in a `List`

`myFunction(people.Select(o => o.FirstName).ToList())`

`Enumerable.Select` is a method that was introduced in C# 3 as part of LINQ.  Read more about LINQ [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx).  See a brief explanation of deferred execution [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397906.aspx).

Comment: I did a little more reading about LINQ and I was fairly impressed that the .Net compiler will optimize some of the queries. One in particular is that if you use the Count method on an IEnumerable, LINQ does not have to iterate, but can use the Count method on the collection if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your methods accept an `IEnumerable<T>` (where T is the value type). For example, `public void Foo(IEnumerable<string> firstNames) { ... }`. This will be valid if you're only looking to iterate over the list and not access it by index as an `IList<T>` would let you do.

Assuming that you're ok with this, you can simply build an Enumerator object by doing the LINQ method: `myPersonsList.Select(person => person.FirstName);`. Due to the nature of how an Enumerable works (deferred execution), it's more efficient than creating a new list, then iterating over it.

Answer (score 0):

I feel both the answers posted above will solve your problem but better to use extension methods rather than your own method.

Example is pasted for your reference.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
        persons.Select(c => c.FirstName).DoSomething();
    }
}

public static class StringListExtension
{
    public static int DoSomething(this IEnumerable<string> strList)
    {
        return strList.Count();
    }
}

class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```